Tron's free bandwidth can't be used to active new address?
Each tron account has up to 600 free bandwidth every 24 hours.
To active a new tron address need 100 band width.
In my test, the 600 bandwidth is not used when active the new account, instead it burnt 0.1 trx to get 100 bandwidth.
Questions:

Does that means the free bandwidth can't be used to active new address, only the ones earned by pledge can ?
Is there any other differences between free & non-free bandwidth, is there a doc for this?
For transfer to a active account, when bandwidth not enough, seems would burn trx to get all bandwidth, and won't use partly bandwidth + partly trx, could u confirm this, thx.

